# MS Access 2007 VBA - Reusable list box code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access 2007 application which has several forms where I've used the same list box design. I have two list boxes, one of which gets values from a table with a query like:

```
SELECT id, value FROM table
```

And the second which is initially empty. In between these two list boxes are add and remove buttons, which are disabled by default. Clicking a value in the first list box enables the add button, and clicking a value in the second list box enables the remove button. Clicking the add button adds the selected item to the second list, and clicking the remove button removes an item for the second list.

The code I have for the add button is as follows ("ALLLIST" refers to the list with the query values, "SELECTEDLIST" is the one that's initially empty) :

```
Dim selectedId, selectedValue, safeValue As String
Dim existing As Boolean
Dim index As Integer

existing = False
selectedId = Me.ALLLIST.Value
index = Me.ALLLIST.ListIndex
selectedValue = Me.ALLLIST.Column(1,index)

'Loop through the list of selected values and see if this one has already been added to the list
For i = 0 To (Me.SELECTEDLIST.ListCount)
    If (Me.SELECTEDLIST.Column(0, i) = selectedId) Then
        existing = True
    End If
Next i

'Only add the value if it's not already on the list
If (existing) Then
    MsgBox "This list can't contain duplicate values", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
Else
    safeValue = Replace(selectedValue & "", "'", "''")
    Me.SELECTEDLIST.AddItem (selectedId & ";'" & safeValue & "'")
    Me.SELECTEDLIST.Value = Null
    Me.REMOVEBUTTON.Enabled = False
End If
```

And the code for the remove button is:

```
Dim numItems, index As Integer
index = Me.SELECTEDLIST.ListIndex

'Remove the selected item and move to the top of the list
Me.SELECTEDLIST.RemoveItem (index)
Me.SELECTEDLIST.Selected(0) = True

numItems = Me.SELECTEDLIST.ListCount

'Cosmetic feature, select the row above the one we're removing
If (index > 0) Then
    Me.SELECTEDLIST.Selected(index - 1) = True
Else
    Me.SELECTEDLIST.Selected(0) = True
End If

'If the list is empty now, disable the remove button
If (numItems = 0) Then
    Me.ALLLIST.SetFocus
    Me.REMOVEBUTTON.Enabled = False
    Me.SELECTEDLIST.Selected(-1) = True
End If
```

What I would like to do is, rather than copy and paste this code all over the place, have this template stored somewhere and then in my form code write something like:

```
hookUpLists(allListName, selectedListName, addButtonName, removeButtonName)
```

How can I do this? Can I write a module to do this some how? I'm also open to any improvements I can make on the above code.

Thanks

Comment: I think you should be able to do this with a class module but it's involving enough that I won't be able to provide details on how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the hint on using class modules, HK1, I'd never used them before.

To solve the original question, I created a new class module "MultiSelectListBox", which has the following code:

```
 Option Compare Database

  Private WithEvents allList As ListBox
  Private WithEvents selectedList As ListBox
  Private WithEvents addBtn As CommandButton
  Private WithEvents removeBtn As CommandButton
  Private numColumns As Integer

  Public Sub hookUpLists(numberOfColumns As Integer, allValuesList As ListBox, selectedValuesList As ListBox, addButton As CommandButton, _
                        removeButton As CommandButton)

    'Grab all the controls passed in
    Set allList = allValuesList
    Set selectedList = selectedValuesList
    Set addBtn = addButton
    Set removeBtn = removeButton
    numColumns = numberOfColumns

    'Tell Access we want to handle the click events for the controls here
    allList.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    selectedList.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    addBtn.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"
    removeBtn.OnClick = "[Event Procedure]"

  End Sub

  Private Sub allList_Click()
    addBtn.Enabled = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub selectedList_Click()
    removeBtn.Enabled = True
  End Sub

  Private Sub addBtn_Click()
    Dim selectedId As String
    Dim existing As Boolean
    Dim index As Integer

    existing = False
    selectedId = allList.Value
    index = allList.ListIndex

    'Loop through the list of selected values and see if this one has already been added to the list
    For i = 0 To (selectedList.ListCount)
        If (selectedList.Column(0, i) = selectedId) Then
            existing = True
        End If
    Next i

    'Only add the value if it's not already on the list
    If (existing) Then
        MsgBox "This list can't contain duplicate values", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim item As String
    item = selectedId & ";"

    'Loop over all of the columns and add them to the second list box
    For i = 1 To numColumns - 1
        item = item & "'" & Replace(allList.Column(i, index) & "", "'", "''") & "'"

        'Don't add a trailing semicolon
        If (i <> numColumns - 1) Then
            item = item & ";"
        End If
    Next i

    selectedList.AddItem (item)
    selectedList.Value = Null
    removeBtn.Enabled = False

    'Select the next row
    If (index <> allList.ListCount - 1) Then
        allList.Selected(index + 1) = True
        allList.Value = allList.Column(0, index + 1)
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub removeBtn_Click()
    Dim numItems, index As Integer
    index = selectedList.ListIndex

    'Remove the selected item and move to the top of the list
    selectedList.RemoveItem (index)
    selectedList.Selected(0) = True

    numItems = selectedList.ListCount

    'Cosmetic feature, select the row above the one we're removing
    If (index > 0) Then
        selectedList.Selected(index - 1) = True
    Else
        selectedList.Selected(0) = True
    End If

    'If the list is empty now, disable the remove button
    If (numItems = 0) Then
        allList.SetFocus
        removeBtn.Enabled = False
        selectedList.Selected(-1) = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Most of the above is identical to what I was already using, one important thing to note for anyone stumbling across this is the use of "WithEvents" when declaring the variables. This tells Access to look in the class module for event handlers. Finally, from my form I can do the following:

```
Private contactList As MultiSelectListBox

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Set contactList = New MultiSelectListBox
    contactList.hookUpLists 3, Me.allContactsList, Me.selectedContactsList, Me.addContactBtn, Me.removeContactBtn
End Sub
```